# Prevent Outlook's Bing Maps from highlighting address

Tags: html, email, outlook, bing-maps

Part of the email campaign I am sending out has a footer with the address of the company. In Outlook, this address gets turned to blue and highlighted, and clicking on it looks up the address in Bing Maps.

Is there a straightforward way to write the address so that it doesn't get recognised by Bing Maps & has the added styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to disable this within your individual email. Note that Outlook only does this if this feature is enabled within your Exchange server.